# How can I use Git to get an idea of the state of the project?

Tags: git

Not sure if I formulated the question well.

We have an editor project at work which now will be used by another company. In order to achieve that we need to strip all the dependencies and much more.

Furthermore, there was one huge refactoring commit as well as a standalone version, which the PO only wants to be applied in some cases.

So we ended up with several branches, a 3 month old `master`, `master-xyz`, a `dev`, `dev-xyz` etc.

My question:

**Is there a tool for Git that helps me to identify the important ones?**

Obviously the 'age' of a branch is relevant but so is probably the size (commits, lines of code). How would you try to figure out what's going on where, and how they relate to each other?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout something like gitkraken. It might be helpful to get a visual idea of whats going on.